# What is the difference between "Visitor pattern" and "Chain of responsibility pattern"?

Tags: design-patterns

I found many differences between many design patterns.

But, I couldn't see the difference between visitor and chain of responsibility in the stackoverflow.

What is the difference between two design patterns?

Comment: There are quite different, why do you think they are similar?

Comment: it is same as a behavioral pattern